# ORMLite vs pure SQLite select performance

Tags: java, sqlite, ormlite

I have database created with ormlite:

When I do query from sqlite console:

```
select * from records

result is:

3520 rows returned in 87ms from: SELECT * FROM `records`
```

Now I do same in ORMLite:

```
DatabaseHelper.get().getRecordsDao().queryForAll();
```

It takes around 70s for this query to finish.

Why is there such big difference???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It takes around 70s for this query to finish.

Depends a lot on your entity and what fields it contains.  If this is under Android, typically the extra time is memory bandwidth.  When you are doing a SQL `select *` it just returns text.  ORMLite processes all of the columns and creates thousand and thousand of objects that correspond to all of the fields in your entity.

Also, if you also have foreign objects that are loaded eagerly, that causes additional queries to be called to flesh out each of the other objects.

Comment: Yeah I found out that ormlite can not generate join select to fetch all at once